# google style right click and drag

Tags: javascript

I like the Gmail facility of going to the next message using right click and drag mouse to the right.

Can I implement that functionality in someone else's website? For example, can I automatically move to the next question / page on the SO site?

Comment: I hear Greasemonkey is good for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can. In programming you can do anything. I mean it.  Anything.   Just give it a try and you will be amazed by what js can do for you.

I would recommend taking a gander at the amazing js libraries out there:

http://demos.mootools.net/

http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html

http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/demos

But basically you would want to click and drag elements right to make the page move to the next page?

Or is this a firefox plugin?

Comment: The OP is talking about someone else's site, not their own so the libraries you reference don't quite solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like mouse gestures.

If you want it for yourself, then use [Opera](http://opera.com) (has them built-in, very well implemented and integrated with "fast forward" which guesses next page on most sites), add extension to Firefox (search for mouse gestures - few options are available) or install system-wide gestures ([xGestures](http://alum.hampshire.edu/~bjk02/xGestures/) for OS X, Stroke-It for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox, there are plugins to get this functionality everywhere:

[All-In-One-Gestures](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6366)

[Firegestures](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12)